# Mysql- Different between two days using TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql

hi i am using MYSQL TIMESTAMPDIFF get the different between two timestamps. 
i can be able to get the value of two time-stamps from below query as follows.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date,
        ' ',
        tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_time
    ) AS dateA,
    CONCAT(
        tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_date,
        ' ',
        tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_time
    ) AS dateB
FROM
    tsp_filtered_data
INNER JOIN tsc_document_status ON tsp_filtered_data.Document_id = tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id
WHERE
    tsp_filtered_data.ESN = '23545692'
```

[image]

but onece i include TIMESTAMPDIFF  it creates an 'unknown field' error.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date,
        ' ',
        tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_time
    ) AS dateA,
    CONCAT(
        tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_date,
        ' ',
        tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_time
    ) AS dateB,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `dateA`, `dateB`)/60 AS DateDifferanceInHours
FROM
    tsp_filtered_data
INNER JOIN tsc_document_status ON tsp_filtered_data.Document_id = tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id
WHERE
    tsp_filtered_data.ESN = '23545692'
```

kindly advice if there are any mistakes done by my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, z.dateA, z.dateB)/60 AS DateDifferanceInHours from(SELECT
CONCAT(
tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_date,
' ',
tsc_document_status.tsc_accepted_Or_Created_time
) AS dateA,
CONCAT(
tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_date,
' ',
tsp_filtered_data.uploaded_time
) AS dateB

FROM
tsp_filtered_data
INNER JOIN tsc_document_status ON tsp_filtered_data.Document_id = tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id
WHERE
tsp_filtered_data.ESN = '23545692')z
```

Comment: Also mention what mistake is done as asked in question.